# Capitalizing the last 2 letters in java

Tags: java

Hi Im a beginer in java andd we were given a assignment to captilize the last 2 letter of any given word can someone help me do that?

I was able to figuire out how to captilize the the 1st and last letter but I have no clue how to cap the last 2 letters?

I also Have clue how to make it in a keyboard input and a have it cap the last 2 lettrs and give a output.

Ex- input eat output- eAT

```
class Main {
    static String FirstAndLast(String str)
    {
        // Create an equivalent char array of given string
        char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {

            // k stores index of first character and i is going to store index of last character.
            int k = i;
            while (i < ch.length && ch[i] != ' ')
                i++;

            // Check if the character is a small letter If yes, then Capitalise
            ch[k] = (char)(ch[k] >= 'a' && ch[k] <= 'z'
                               ? ((int)ch[k] - 32)
                               : (int)ch[k]);
            ch[i - 1] = (char)(ch[i - 1] >= 'a' && ch[i - 1] <= 'z'
                                   ? ((int)ch[i - 1] - 32)
                                   : (int)ch[i - 1]);
        }
        return new String(ch);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = "Prep insta";
        System.out.println("Input String:- "+str);
        System.out.println("String after Capitalize the first and last character of each word in a string:- "+FirstAndLast(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to look at the following methods of `java.lang.String`: `substring`, `length`, `toUpperCase` - with them, you can save yourself from fiddling with individual characters, and even get proper capitalization for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Note, there's no need for loops at all in your assignment.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp true, unless using asm ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simpler approach

1. Get a string
2. Cut 2 last letters and remember them
3. Capitalize them
4. Join 2 parts together

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String input="yourInputFromSomewhere";
       int cutPoint=input.length()-2;
       String fixed=input.substring(0,cutPoint);
       String toCapitalize=input.substring(cutPoint);
       System.out.println(fixed+toCapitalize.toUpperCase());
   }
   ```

Output:

> yourInputFromSomewheRE

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to use the base string methods:

```java
String input = "capitalize";
String output = input.substring(0, input.length() - 2) +
                input.substring(input.length() - 2).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(output);  // capitaliZE
```